# Insert multiple records into table when there is a unique field

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a form which inserts a unique code into the table generated through php. It works when there is a single one but when I insert two at the same time I got a duplicate error.

```
if (!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {

  $orderreference = $_SESSION['ref'];

  foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item) {

        if($item['isVoucher'] == 1){

        $insertQuery = ("INSERT INTO `bookings_css_codes` 
                                (`id`, `code`, `price`, `per`, `status`, 
                                `expiry_date`, `usage`, `is_used`) 
                        VALUES ('', '$randomsA', '$item[ProductPrice]', 'amount', 'T', 
                                '$oneYearOn', 'single', '0');");

        if (!$db->query($insertQuery)) {
            die('Error: ' . $db->error);
       }

    }
```

Comment: check to see if it exists first, or try `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. Hard to say though if duplicates are allowed or not.

Comment: If a field is indexed as unique, you simply can't insert two records with the same value. That's the reason for defining it as "unique" in the first place. What exactly is it you're trying to do? What's the expected outcome? If you explain more about your application, we can see if you need to update and normalize your database design.

Comment: What's the problem? Error is absolutely correct behaviour in such a case.

Comment: WHICH column(s) are supposed to be unique on this table?

Comment: I want to insert two records at the same time

Comment: Its called 'Code', it inserts 1 no problem when I try to insert two new records at the same time it give me a problem

Comment: Well according to this code you show, you dont change the value in `$randomsA` between iterations of the loop

Comment: How do i change the value of $randomA between itetartion in the loop ?

Answer (score -2):

you can try

`insert in "field name"("value1","value2",...."valuen");`

Comment: Can you be more clear about that? What is it that the OP should try?

Comment: insert in "table name" "column name"('value1,'vaslue2');

Comment: What do you mean by that? How does this differ from the original query?